# Возможно ли прекратить Console.ReadLine?

Tags: c#, многопоточность, консоль, асинхронность

В общем сразу в чём заключается проблема... есть программа в которой как правило есть главный метод `main` в котором сначала идёт инициализация потока(следующее предложение про него) и сразу же после идёт бесконечный цикл (для того что-бы прога не вылетала после ввода), а потом идёт `Console.ReadLine`(назовём "`ввод 1`", для понятности) и это всё твориться в `main`'e, так вот есть ещё асинхронный поток который может в любой момент сделать callback (но это чисто формальности, всё работает) и короче может вызвать ещё один `Console.ReadLine` (`ввод 2`)... ну вот, при запуске сначала срабатывает `ввод 1`, а затем `ввод 2`, так вот в чём и проблема, когда срабатывает `callback` у асинхронного потока и вызывается `ввод 2`, то когда я ввожу что-нибудь то этот ввод срабатывает на `main` потоке, а затем сразу же срабатывает `ввод 2`, но мне же нужно чтобы был сразу `ввод 2`, а он мне ещё `ввод 1` оставляет, как "вырубить" `ввод 1`? Ну как-то так...

P.S. Пробовал синхронизировать потоки но не помогает, ошибок нет, но и пользы нет.

Comment: Не проще было бы просто привести код, вместо хоть и подробного, но описания?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9479573/interrupt-console-readline